# Ruby-on-Rails using jquery mobile, redirect not change the url

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-mobile, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a problem login and some action form with jquery mobile.
When I try to login account, it go to controller session - action create .

```
def create 
   ...
   redirect_to root_path
end
```

after login it change page home fine, but url still keep localhost:3000/users/sign_in

How to fix this?

Answer (score 8):

I have tested jQuery mobile with Rails 3.2.3 and mobylette gem for browser detection.
In your application layout file add the data-url attribute with request data from rails.

`<div data-role="page" data-url="<%= request.path %>">`

more information here (external links, dialogs):

[Page Links Jquery mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/pages/page-links.html)