# redirect after logging in successfully but still have original URL shown in browser address bar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm developing user authentication using devise. The sign-in page is like 
localhost:3000/users/sign_in. After sign-in successful (a Post request), the user is redirected to home page (localhost:3000/). This is expected, and I do see the home page content loaded in browser.

However, the browser address bar still shows the original request url as localhost:3000/users/sign_in

Any idea why this is happening? Is it devise config thing or is it rails server?
I didn't have much my own code here, pretty much just hooked up with default devise options for my User model.

Here are part of my routes:

```
new_user_session GET  /users/sign_in(.:format)  devise/sessions#new
user_session     POST /users/sign_in(.:format)  devise/sessions#create
root                  /                         home#index
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your `after_sign_in_path_for` method from your ApplicationController

Comment: My ApplicationController is actually empty, so I'm using the devise's original "after_sign_in_path_for". So the default behavior is to redirect to the root which is "/" in my case.

Comment: I have an app that is similar to yours then, using the default after_sign_in_path_for, and if im not logged in, it redirects to the sign_in page, then when I log in it redirects to the root url. Are you sure your root url isn't the same as the sign_in url? The default functionality works pretty standard.

Comment: I have added my related routes in the original post. As you can see, it's not the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it has sth. to do with my jquery mobile inclusion. 
This link here solved my question:

[rubyrails using jquery mobile, redirect not change url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10425000/rubyrails-using-jquery-mobile-redirect-not-change-url)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code block from latest devise version

File: `../gems/devise-2.1.2/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb`

```
# POST /resource/sign_in
def create
  resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
  set_flash_message(:notice, :signed_in) if is_navigational_format?
  sign_in(resource_name, resource)
  respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
end

def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
  stored_location_for(resource_or_scope) || signed_in_root_path(resource_or_scope)
end

def signed_in_root_path(resource_or_scope)
  scope = Devise::Mapping.find_scope!(resource_or_scope)
  home_path = "#{scope}_root_path"
  if respond_to?(home_path, true)
    send(home_path)
  elsif respond_to?(:root_path)
    root_path
  else
    "/"
  end
end
```

If you root configured to Home#Index for example and it's protected by `before_filter :authenticate_user!` then after entering user name and password the url must be your domain name.

Comment: Actually, my Home#index does not even have this before_filter :authenticate_user! yet. But still, after sign_in success, home page content is loaded but the URL in the address bar remains as /users/sign_in.  Same thing happens for sign_out as well.

Comment: You should definitely add that, otherwise your sign in is useless.

Comment: right. but for now, it's just in initial stage. We will need to figure out what pages should be guarded, but not the home page yet at this time. It's a different topic but thanks for the reminding.