# redirect_to and update the URL jQuery mobile & Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a JQM page in my webapp with a URL like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/technician/BSON ID IS HERE/signature
```

There is a 'Next' button which is the submit on the form to submit a customer's signature.

We happily hit the submit_sign action in the controller and make a nice png out of the signature and upload that to AWS.  When we're done, we want to redirect_to another page.

We redirect_to our documents page and render the documents.html.erb view.

The only problem (a big problem) is that the URL is now:

```
http://localhost:8080/technician/52a64f5e625c6c0272000047/submit_sign
```

The documents page has been rendered of course, and it's fully-functional, but you can imagine what happens if:

A) the user tries to hit the back button on the browser
B) the user switches to a different app on their phone, then returns to the browser (forcing a reload)

Errors galore because submit_sign has no corresponding view template.

This question was asked a YEAR ago on SO and no answers so far:  [Rails redirect_to shows incorrect URL in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12394879/rails-redirect-to-shows-incorrect-url-in-browser)

Answer (score 0):

As so often is the case...  Post question, get frustrated, go on a rage of Googling random things you hadn't thought to combine before - finally find answer on someone else's post who phrased their request slightly differently than you did...

[THE ANSWER FROM ANOTHER SO POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10425000/rubyrails-using-jquery-mobile-redirect-not-change-url)

In Rails & JQM - you basically need this in every header (just to be safe!)

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1" data-url="<%= request.path %>">
```

Your ID will vary of course.